# How to convert 'binary string' to normal string in Python3?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, binary

For example, I have a string like this(return value of `subprocess.check_output`):

```
>>> b'a string'
b'a string'
```

Whatever I did to it, it is always printed with the annoying `b'` before the string:

```
>>> print(b'a string')
b'a string'
>>> print(str(b'a string'))
b'a string'
```

Does anyone have any ideas about how to use it as a normal string or convert it into a normal string?

Comment: @HanfeiSun what you call a "*binary string*" is a **bytes object** (see [information about *bytes object* in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typebytes) )

Answer (score 615, accepted):

Decode it.

```
>>> b'a string'.decode('ascii')
'a string'
```

To get bytes from string, encode it.

```
>>> 'a string'.encode('ascii')
b'a string'
```

Comment: @lyomi, I used `ascii` because the given string was made with ascii letters. You don't need to specify encoding if the encoding is `utf-8` (default in Python 3.x according to `str.encode`, `bytes.decode` doc-string)

Comment: @lyomi In 2016 (and its nearly the end) people still use ascii. There are many many 'legacy' products and systems (including specifications), but there are also lots of reasons why you might be creating a 'binary string' where you don't want unicode or something to try and 'merge' multiple bytes into a single character. We often use 'strings' to contain binary data for instance making DNS requests etc.

Comment: I suggest to add the following to complete the answer. Most times we need to decode bytes from our operating system, such as console output, the most pythonic way I found to do it is to `import locale` and then `os_encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()`. This way, we can decode using `my_b_string.decode(os_encoding)`

Comment: @aturegano, It's not the only option. `sys.getfilesystemencoding()`, `sys.stdin.encoding`, `sys.stdout.encoding`. IMHO, using those automatic encoding detection could solve problem because the sub-program (OP is using subprocess) could be written other way to determine encoding (or even hard-coded). Thanks for feedback, anyway.

Comment: @falsetru Note that `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` returns the name of the encoding used to convert between Unicode filenames and bytes filenames and is strongly dependant on operating system you are using. AFAIK, this function is used to convert to the system’s preferred representation. That means that it will not infer the codification used by the console that can be obtained using the aforementioned `locale.getpreferredencoding()` function

Comment: @aturegano, subprocess.check_output can return arbitrary byte string, it could be a file system path. You know my point, right?

Comment: @lyomi long live ascii

Answer (score 129):

If the answer from [falsetru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225682/falsetru) didn't work you could also try:

```
>>> b'a string'.decode('utf-8')
'a string'
```

Answer (score 12):

See the official `encode()` and `decode()` documentation from [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.encode) library. `utf-8` is the default encoding for the functions, but there are severals [standard encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) in Python 3, like `latin_1` or `utf_32`.