# How to convert a binary representation of a string back to the original string in Python?

Tags: python, decode, binary-data

I haven't been able to find an answer to the following question:
Start with a string, convert it to its binary representation. How do you get back the original string in Python?

Example:

```
a = 'hi us'
b = ''.join(format(ord(c), '08b') for c in a)
```

then `b = 0110100001101001001000000111010101110011`

Now I want to get 'hi us' back in Python 2.x. For example, this website accomplishes the task:
http://string-functions.com/binary-string.aspx

I've seen several answers for Java, but haven't had luck implementing to Python. I've also tried `b.decode()`, but don't know which encoding I should use in this case.

Comment: [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615414/how-to-convert-binary-string-to-normal-string-in-python3)

Comment: thank you, but they use 'ascii' to decode, which is not relevant to my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this code:

```
import binascii
n = int('0110100001101001001000000111010101110011', 2)
binascii.unhexlify('%x' % n)
```

Comment: how about much longer strings ?

Comment: @user 12321, perfect! exactly what I need. thank you. will accept your answer asap

Comment: to my surprise, it does! python apparently does not have much problem with the notion of insanely large integers

Comment: any further comments on 'efficiency' would be nice. my general question would be: given, say, a string s with len(s) < 25, convert s *uniquely* to a numerical type, then convert back to get s.

Comment: importing binascii will help u and is pretty fast, to make a binarry number out of text use this code: `import binascii
 bin(int(binascii.hexlify('hello'), 16)) `  and to make it back to string use the answer I posted to your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> print ''.join(chr(int(b[i:i+8], 2)) for i in range(0, len(b), 8))
'hi us'
```

Split b in chunks of 8, parse to int using radix 2, convert to char, join the resulting list as a string.