# How to extract substring from a 'binary string' in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string `b'helloworld\n'`. I want to extract `helloworld` from it. For this, I am doing

`print(string[1:-2])`

But on output I am getting `b'elloworl'`.

How can I extraxt helloworld.

Thanks

Comment: try `string[0:-1]`.

Comment: @Ho0ony Output is `b'helloworld'`

Comment: `b` in front of string is a string literal which means string would of bytes type instead of `str` type and don't impact literal meaning of the string. See https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals for more info.

Comment: @apsdehal Thanks. I solved it using `string.decode("utf-8")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17615424/6900838), to change binary string to normal string use this:

```
>>> b'helloworld\n'.decode('ascii') # you can use utf8 or something else, it is up to you
'helloworld\n'
```

To delete whitespaces use `strip()`:

```
>>> b'helloworld\n'.decode('ascii').strip()
'helloworld'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
print(s[0:-1])
```

Indexes are zero based so the h is at index zero. The ending index is non-inclusive, so go one extra.

If you want to get rid of the b you have to decode the bytes object.

```
print(s.decode('utf-8')[0:-1])
```