# Converting binary to string in python

Tags: python, string, binary

I am currently struggling with binary to string conversion in python. Thanks to the bin fonction, the opposite conversion is simple, but I can't find on the internet how to do so. If one of you is willing to help, I'd welcome any answer. thanks

Comment: Can you show us the code you already have?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Convert base-2 binary number string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8928240/1288)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert 'binary string' to normal string in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615414/how-to-convert-binary-string-to-normal-string-in-python3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert base-2 binary number string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928240/convert-base-2-binary-number-string-to-int)

Answer (score 1):

```
binary_string = b'test'
print(binary_string)
regular_string = binary_string.decode('utf-8')
print(regular_string)
```

Output:

```
b'test'
test
```