# How to get actual string from a line-json file in Python3?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have to read a line-json and extract the key from each line. Eventually, this is to be deleted from ES' index.

However, upon reading the file, the values extracted are:
`b'74298dcbd08507175b94fbe5c2a6a87d'` instead of `74298dcbd08507175b94fbe5c2a6a87d`. The code that reads the lines(from files) is:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
import json

es = Elasticsearch("a.b.c.d:9200")
delete_patch_destination = "delete.json"
index_name = "some_index"

with open(delete_patch_destination) as delete_json_file:
    for line in delete_json_file:
        # print(line)
        line_content = json.loads(line)
        # line_content = json.loads(line)
        # for es_key in line_content.items():
        for es_key in line_content.keys():
            print (es_key)
            # es.delete(index=index_name, doc_type="latest",id=es_key)
```

The json file comprises of lines:

```
{"b'af2f9719a205f0ce9ae27c951e5b7037'": "\"b'af2f9719a205f0ce9ae27c951e5b7037'\""}
{"b'2b2781de47c70b11576a0f67bc59050a'": "\"b'2b2781de47c70b11576a0f67bc59050a'\""}
{"b'6cf97818c6b5c5a94b7d8dbb4cfcfe60'": "\"b'6cf97818c6b5c5a94b7d8dbb4cfcfe60'\""}
{"b'ceaf66243d3eb226859ee5ae7eacf86a'": "\"b'ceaf66243d3eb226859ee5ae7eacf86a'\""}
{"b'164a12ea5947e1f51566ee6939e20a2e'": "\"b'164a12ea5947e1f51566ee6939e20a2e'\""}
{"b'42e9bb704c424b49fb5e6adb68157e6f'": "\"b'42e9bb704c424b49fb5e6adb68157e6f'\""}
```

Comment: I'd vouch for `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: That fails a lot, as I have read in other cases. Any other or more reliable way?

Or maybe I am wrong to consider `ast.literal_eval` dangerous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input could be improved to avoid those convolutions, but to fix your immediate problem:

your dictionary seems to consist of a key and the same data as value (even more "stringified, we'll ignore that part)

first evaluate using `ast.literal_eval`, then decode the key to convert to string:

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "b'af2f9719a205f0ce9ae27c951e5b7037'"
>>> ast.literal_eval(s).decode()
'af2f9719a205f0ce9ae27c951e5b7037'
```

(as opposed to `eval` this method of evaluation doesn't have security issues: [Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval))

Answer (score 1):

decode the string like:

[How to convert 'binary string' to normal string in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615414/how-to-convert-binary-string-to-normal-string-in-python3)

```js
b'a_string'.decode('utf-8')
```

you will get 'a_string'