# Python Mysql Connector Giving output in bytearray

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WH42.png)

when i perform query like show databases or show tables it shows outputs in something called byte array. i want the output in normal String form . can someone tell how can i fix this

```py
def tab(x,y):
    x=[]
    mycursor.execute("Show databases")  #Selecting Database
    l=list(mycursor.fetchall())
    print(l)
```

```````output``

(bytearray(b'capital'),)
(bytearray(b'capital_user'),)
(bytearray(b'information_schema'),)
(bytearray(b'mysql'),)
(bytearray(b'performance_schema'),)
(bytearray(b'sys'),)

Comment: Please post your code here

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code and output **as text**. Screenshots of text are not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -2):

that is called binary string,, just convert it normally.. here is reference how to convert it [How to convert 'binary string' to normal string in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615414/how-to-convert-binary-string-to-normal-string-in-python3)