# Python method not working what i need to do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, replace, valueerror

I writing a gamepad serial-driver for Arduino UNO, so, in Arduino IDE coord resives good. But in PySerial adding b' and \r\n' in the end. I added `replace()`, but nothing changed...
There is code:
import pyautogui, sys
import time
import serial

```
ArduinoSerial=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',115200)  #Specify the correct COM port
time.sleep(1)                             #delay of 1 second
a = 1
while a:
    ArduinoSerial.readline()
    print(ArduinoSerial.readline());

    data=str(ArduinoSerial.readline())
    data = data.replace("\r\n", "")
    print(data)
    (x,y)=data.split(":")           # read the x and y axis data
    (X,Y)=pyautogui.position()        #read the current cursor's position
    x=int(x)
    y=int(y)
    pyautogui.moveTo(X+x,Y-y)           #move cursor to desired position
```

There is output:

```
ilyabot@ilyabot-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~/Рабочий стол$ python3 joy_driver.py 
b'0:0\r\n'
b'0:0\r\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "joy_driver.py", line 21, in <module>
    x=int(x)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "b'0"
```

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615414/how-to-convert-binary-string-to-normal-string-in-python3) for how to correctly convert a binary string to regular string using `.decode()` instead of `str()`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed problem... And found new... There is no error now, there is only empty and **nothing**... pyautogui want to work :<
My System: *Xubuntu 18.04 x86_64*
Python: *Python 3.6.9*

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

```
data = data[:-5]
```

I replaced data = data.replace("\r\n'", "") at data = data[:-5] and IT WORKS!!!

There is all code:

```
# Importing modules
import pyautogui, sys
import time 
import serial
# Arduino Serial-Joystick Driver
SerialConnection=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',115200)  # Specify the your COM port
while 1:
    data = str(SerialConnection.readline()) # Read the x and y axis data
    data = data.replace("b'", "") # Eraing "b'"
    data = data[:-5] # Easing "\r\n'"
    (x,y)=data.split(":") # Adding ":" split
    print(data) # Logging
    (X,Y)=pyautogui.position()        # Read the current cursor's position
    x=int(x) # Converting str(x) to int(x)
    y=int(y) # Converting str(y) to int(y)
    pyautogui.moveTo(X-x,Y+y) # Move cursor to desired position
```

Comment: You can probably just do `data = SerialConnection.readline().decode().strip()` and then split it