# python return xmlblock and remove encoding tag

Tags: python, xml, encoding

I am trying to edit an xml file.

The file i get, where the new information is stored, looks like this:

```
    <Symbols>
        <Symbol>
            <Name TaskPrio="1">dummyName</Name>
            <Type>dummyType</Type>
            <Comment>
                <!dummyComment>
            </Comment>
            <IGroup>Number</IGroup>
            <IOffset>Number</IOffset>
            <BitSize>Number</BitSize>
        </Symbol>
        <Symbol>
            <Name TaskPrio="1">dummyName</Name>
            <Type>dummyType</Type>
            <Comment>
                <!dummyComment>
            </Comment>
            <IGroup>Number</IGroup>
            <IOffset>Number</IOffset>
            <BitSize>Number</BitSize>
        </Symbol>
        ...
   </Symbols>
```

The part of the file where i need to insert the new information(different xml file) looks like this:

```
<VariableList>
  <Variable>
    <Name Type="4" AreaType="1" Address="0" Bit="0" Description="DummyDescription" Group="DummyGroup" Shared="0" Retentive="0" DynamicSettings="DummyDinamycSettings">VariableName</Name>
    <EnableTrace>0</EnableTrace>
    <EnableOPCUAServer>0</EnableOPCUAServer>
    <EnableOPCServer>0</EnableOPCServer>
    <EnableNetworkClient>0</EnableNetworkClient>
    <EnableMapRealTimeToDB>0</EnableMapRealTimeToDB>
  </Variable>
</VariableList>
```

I already managed to fish out the information I need and format it in the xmlblock I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Variable>
  <Name Type="4" AreaType="1" Address="0" Bit="0" Description="DummyDescription" Group="DummyGroup" Shared="0" Retentive="0" DynamicSettings="DummyDinamycSettings">VariableName</Name>
  <EnableTrace>0</EnableTrace>
  <EnableOPCUAServer>0</EnableOPCUAServer>
  <EnableOPCServer>0</EnableOPCServer>
  <EnableNetworkClient>0</EnableNetworkClient>
  <EnableMapRealTimeToDB>0</EnableMapRealTimeToDB>
</Variable>

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Variable>
  <Name Type="4" AreaType="1" Address="0" Bit="0" Description="DummyDescription" Group="DummyGroup" Shared="0" Retentive="0" DynamicSettings="DummyDinamycSettings">VariableName</Name>
  <EnableTrace>0</EnableTrace>
  <EnableOPCUAServer>0</EnableOPCUAServer>
  <EnableOPCServer>0</EnableOPCServer>
  <EnableNetworkClient>0</EnableNetworkClient>
  <EnableMapRealTimeToDB>0</EnableMapRealTimeToDB>
</Variable>
```

With the following code:

```
    def getVarBlock(self, variables, stationName):
        def prettify(elem):
            """Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element.
            """
            rough_string = ET.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
            reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
            return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ")

        end_list = []
        for vars in variables:
            varTyp = '0'
            xmlVariable = ET.Element('Variable')
            name = ET.SubElement(xmlVariable, 'Name')
            if vars['Name'].startswith(self.settings.type0Vars[0]):                             
                varTyp = '0'
                name.attrib['Type'] = '0'
            elif vars['Name'].startswith(self.settings.type2Vars[0]):                           
                varTyp = '2'
                name.attrib['Type'] = '2'
            elif vars['Name'].startswith(self.settings.type4Vars[0]):                           
                varTyp = '4'
                name.attrib['Type'] = '4'
            elif vars['Name'].startswith(self.settings.type6Vars[0]):                           
                varTyp = '6'
                name.attrib['Type'] = '6'
            elif vars['Name'].startswith(self.settings.type7Vars[0]):                           
                varTyp = '7'
                name.attrib['Type'] = '7'
            elif self.settings.type10Vars[0] in vars['Name']:                                     
                varTyp = '10'
                name.attrib['Type'] = '10'
            elif vars['Name'].startswith(self.settings.type11Vars[0]):                          
                varTyp = '11'
                name.attrib['Type'] = '11'
            else:
                name.attrib['Type'] = ' '

            name.attrib['AreaType'] = '1'
            name.attrib['Address'] = '0'
            name.attrib['Bit'] = '0'
            name.attrib['Description'] = vars['Comment']

            if vars['Name'].startswith('r'):
                name.attrib['Group'] = 'ANALOG'
            elif vars['Name'].startswith('b'):
                name.attrib['Group'] = 'DIGITAL'
            elif vars['Name'].startswith('st'):
                name.attrib['Group'] = 'STRUCTURES'
            else:
                name.attrib['Group'] = 'VARIABLES'

            name.attrib['Shared'] = '0'
            name.attrib['Retentive'] = '0'
            name.attrib['DynamicSettings'] = '[DRV]TwinCAT.Sta=' + stationName + '|SA=.' + vars['Name'] + '|Typ='+ varTyp +''
            name.text = vars['Name']

            enableTrace = SubElement(xmlVariable, 'EnableTrace')
            enableTrace.text = '0'

            enableOPCUAServer = SubElement(xmlVariable, 'EnableOPCUAServer')
            enableOPCUAServer.text = '0'

            enableOPCServer = SubElement(xmlVariable, 'EnableOPCServer')
            enableOPCServer.text = '0'

            enableNetworkClient = SubElement(xmlVariable, 'EnableNetworkClient')
            enableNetworkClient.text = '0'

            enableMapRealTimeToDB = SubElement(xmlVariable, 'EnableMapRealTimeToDB')
            enableMapRealTimeToDB.text = '0'

            end_list.append(prettify(xmlVariable))

        for line in end_list:
            print(line)

        return print(xmlVariable)
```

And here are the problems i encounter:

- Why are the blocks separated by a new line and the encoding tag?
- How do I get rid of the encoding tag?
- And how do i return the new xmlblocks in the function in a decent way to use later when writing the file?

Comment: Seems you are using lxml and minidom while you could use just lxml. Add the imports to the code and also add a sample of what do you expect to get.

Comment: the imports i use:
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom...the output i expect i as above just without the encoding line

Comment: My answer below does that. Inside `prettify` just do `return etree.tostring(elem,pretty_print=True)`. Add indent argument as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty print an element only with lxml

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> e1 = etree.Element("root")
>>> e2 = etree.Element("child")
>>> e2.text = "algo"
>>> e1.append(e2)
>>> etree.tostring(e1,pretty_print=True)
b'<root>\n  <child>algo</child>\n</root>\n'

>>> etree.tostring(e1,pretty_print=True).decode('utf-8')
'<root>\n  <child>algo</child>\n</root>\n'

>>> print(etree.tostring(e1,pretty_print=True))
<root>
  <child>algo</child>
</root>
```

No XML declaration on top, just the element's content.

This creates a XML representation of the string that when printed will include the XML declaration

```
minidom.parseString(rough_string)
```

Comment: Okay, i succesfully managed to implement sour solution. Thank you!
But how should i return the xmlblocks correctly? If i do a return i only get the last one...

Answer (score 0):

@LMC

i managed to implement your suggestion, and it is giving me the output i need.
But when i print it all, i only get it with the characters '\n' and not in "pretty".

I modified the function like this, i hope i interpreted your answer right.

```
        def prettify(elem):
            pretty = ET.tostring(elem,pretty_print=True)
            return pretty
```

Comment: `return print(pretty)` the `print` function will parse those `\n`.

Comment: somehow that does not work for me, i get ir all out as string with the '\n' and  a 'b' at the beginning of the string...`b'<Variable>\n...`

Comment: You could try `return pretty.decode('utf-8')` as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35948400/2834978